# Let $H$ be a normal of order $6$. If $f :G\to G_1$ be an epimorphism of groups s.t. $H\subset{\rm Ker}(f)$, then show $G_1$ is a hom. image of $G/H$.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, group-isomorphism, epimorphisms

Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of order $6$. If $f :G\longrightarrow G_1$ be an epimorphism of groups such that $H\subset \mathrm{Ker} (f)$, then show that $G_1$ is also a homomorphic image of $G/H$.

In this problem, from the first isomorphism theorem, we can say that $G/\mathrm{Ker}(f)\cong G_1$. Hence, there exists an isomorphism $f:G/\mathrm{Ker}(f)\longrightarrow G_1$, such that $f$ is bijective. Given, $H\subset \mathrm{Ker}( f)$, if we consider the same function $f:G/H\longrightarrow G_1$, then we can probably think this situation where, the *original domain* of $f$ have been *shrinked* and this change keeps the property of $f$ invariant except the fact $f$ does not remain onto. But $f$ is still a homomorphism, due to which the fact that $G_1$ is also a homomorphic image of $G/H$ follows trivially.

Can this considered a **valid solution**? If not, then I need an *explicit reason* for the same. I know there are posts associated with this particular topic in this thread, but I want to know whether **this particular** solution is valid or, not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is flawed, at the least,
in that once again the expression "homomorphic image" means a *surjective* homomorphism. If you were just looking for *any* homomorphism,  there's always the trivial one.

---

This follows from the *universal property of quotient groups*.  See [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Universal_Property_of_Quotient_Group).

There's a  unique homomorphism $\bar f:G/H\twoheadrightarrow G_1, $ where $f=\bar f\circ \pi$, and $\pi$ is the canonical projection onto $G/H.$

I don't see any need that $H$ have order $6$.

Comment: But why is my solution flawed?

Comment: The shrinking idea is too vague.   You do need a surjection,  and it's not clear what you're doing.  The domain is actually getting larger.

Comment: Thank you! But I don't get how the domain gets larger? Is this because,  the size of the domain comparing $G/H$ as the  new domain and $G/\text{Ker }f$ as the original domain, when $H\subseteq \text{Ker}f$, so, $o(H)\leq o(\text{Ker}f)$ and hence, $$o(G/\text{Ker}f)(=o(G)/o(\text{Ker}f))<o(G/H)(=o(G)/o(\text{Ker}f))$$?, right? This is the actual reason why my proof fails ,right?...

Comment: Basically.   That's right.